# Slidingdrawer Android with fill_parent option

Tags: android, android-layout, slidingdrawer

I can't seem to get my sliding drawer the way I want to. I would like it to stretch all the way to the top of the layout, which is not a problem...the problem is that the layout beneath it isn't visible anymore if i remove the transparency option. 
I would like the drawer to be almost opaque (somewhere like #D000), but without affecting the layer beneath it when it is closed. Could it be done with XML only?
In the madness and despair I have also tried flipping the order of the drawer and the table layout, which of course only resulted in failure as expected...

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="30dip"
        android:background="#fff"  >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginBottom="25dip"
            android:text="@string/main_menu_select"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="@dimen/dimenLabel" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/accommodation_cb"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/accommodation"
            android:textColor="#000" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/food_and_beverage_cb"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/food_and_beverage"
            android:textColor="#000" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/fun_cb"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/fun"
            android:textColor="#000" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/transport_cb"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/transport" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/other_cb"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/other" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/submit_button"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="checkListing"
            android:text="@string/submit_label" />
    </TableLayout>

    <SlidingDrawer
        android:id="@+id/SlidingDrawer"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="#D000"
        android:content="@+id/contentLayout"
        android:handle="@+id/slideButton"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="10dip" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/slideButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="^" >
        </Button>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/contentLayout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="10dip" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/Button01"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="2dp"
                android:text="Button 1" >
            </Button>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/Button02"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="2dp"
                android:text="Button 2" >
            </Button>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/Button03"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="2dp"
                android:text="Button 3" >
            </Button>
        </LinearLayout>
    </SlidingDrawer>

</RelativeLayout>
```

My main class is default view inflating this layout. 
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You are currently working under the assumption that a color is represented by a single byte.  But that is not the case.  Each color is represented by two bytes per color.  So if you were trying to provide a color with `#fff` for instance then a full opaque version of that would really be `#FFFFFF` without alpha or `#FFFFFFFF` with alpha.

You should start with that, and then re-test with your opacity and update your question perhaps.  If you are getting a transparent drawer, then it shouldn't affect the data behind it, so I am unclear as to what you are requesting.

Comment: It is the same thing...or at least it gives the same output. My problem is that if the drawer is not fully transparent, that it affects the color of the layout beneath it. So in this example, without the drawer, my checkboxes would be pure black on white, however, with opaque drawer, the whole layout with checkboxes gets semi-transparent overlay, or fully opaque overlay, depending on alpha for the drawer I provide

Comment: You are saying that the drawer when its closed is affecting the view of your original layout?  Just because the drawer exists?  That would be an odd one.

Comment: Exactly...can it be the emulator thing? I would post a scrnsht, but with current reputation I can't yet upload pictures

Comment: I am really more familiar with using the android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout class instead of the SlidingDrawer class to be honest, but unsure as to why it might be doing that.  It sounds as though the drawer there might not fully be closing for some reason.

Comment: It seems like the drawer layout occupies the space I give it in layout_height option. So if I put height to say 150dip, it will occupy one third of the screen when closed like its "saving" the space for where the drawer should be opened...Damn, thanks anyway